# Object is not rendering/drawing using triangles and coordinates, SceneKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit, scnnode

The problem is that I can't render anything if I create `SCNGeometry` using this constructor `init(sources: [AnyObject], elements: [AnyObject]?)` Here is an example (this should draw a cube, taken from this [tutorial](http://ronnqvi.st/custom-scenekit-geometry/)):

```
func test()
{
    var cubeSide:Float = 15.0;
    var halfSide:Float = cubeSide/2;

    var positions:[SCNVector3] = [
        SCNVector3Make(-halfSide, -halfSide,  halfSide),
        SCNVector3Make( halfSide, -halfSide,  halfSide),
        SCNVector3Make(-halfSide, -halfSide, -halfSide),
        SCNVector3Make( halfSide, -halfSide, -halfSide),
        SCNVector3Make(-halfSide,  halfSide,  halfSide),
        SCNVector3Make( halfSide,  halfSide,  halfSide),
        SCNVector3Make(-halfSide,  halfSide, -halfSide),
        SCNVector3Make( halfSide,  halfSide, -halfSide)
    ];

    var indices:[Int] = [
        0, 2, 1,
        1, 2, 3,
        // back
        2, 6, 3,
        3, 6, 7,
        // left
        0, 4, 2,
        2, 4, 6,
        // right
        1, 3, 5,
        3, 7, 5,
        // front
        0, 1, 4,
        1, 5, 4,
        // top
        4, 5, 6,
        5, 7, 6
    ];

    var geometrySource = SCNGeometrySource(vertices: positions, count: 8)

    var data = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(Int) * indices.count)

    var element = SCNGeometryElement(data: data, primitiveType: SCNGeometryPrimitiveType.Triangles, primitiveCount: 12, bytesPerIndex: sizeof(Int))

    var geometry = SCNGeometry(sources: [geometrySource], elements: [element])
    geometry.materials?.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()

    var node = SCNNode(geometry: geometry)

    /*var cameraNode:SCNNode = SCNNode()
    cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
    cameraNode.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 12, 30);
    self.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode);*/

    self.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
}
```

But the screen is just empty:
[image: IPad emulator]

If I create geometry from known figures, everything is ok. Code example:

```
func showCone()
{
    var radius:CGFloat = 1.0

    let cone = SCNCone(topRadius: 0.1, bottomRadius: 3, height: 2)
    cone.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.redColor()

    let coneNode = SCNNode(geometry: cone)
    coneNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 4.0, y: 3.0, z: 20.0)

    self.rootNode.addChildNode(coneNode)
}
```

How it looks like:
[image: IPad emulator]

I thought the problem was the camera node, but I've done a lot of manipulations and nothing changed. Changing node `position` also didn't help. Also, it works if I create a new Xcode project, which deployment target is OS X. But I need a solution for iOS.

What is my mistake, what am i doing wrong?

Initially my problem was that I couldn't draw 3d-model from parsed `.stl` file. I thought the problem was parsing but then I tried to draw anything using primitive type - triangles and their positions, and it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SceneKit does not handle `Int` indices because their value can be too large. You should see this in the console:

> SceneKit: error, C3DRendererContextBindMeshElement unsupported byte per index (8)

Use `UInt8` instead:

```
 var indices:[UInt8] = ...
```

Also note that, in Swift, there's a helper to build a geometry element.
The following lines

```
var data = NSData(bytes: indices, length: sizeof(Int) * indices.count)
var element = SCNGeometryElement(data: &data, primitiveType: .Triangles, primitiveCount: 12, bytesPerIndex: sizeofValue(indices[0]))
```

become

```
var element = SCNGeometryElement(indices: indices, primitiveType: .Triangles)
```

Comment: I've changed type to UInt8, and now got en error 'C3DRendererContextSetupResidentMeshSourceAtLocation - double not supported'. Btw didn't get the second part of your answer about helper, because it's just a compilation error if I write like you did.

Comment: position and normals sources should be created from array of floats (`[Float]`). As for the convenience method, please make sure that you are using the latest toolchain (Xcode 7.0.1).

Comment: thank you so much, actually code was correct, but I used Xcode version 7.0, after update everything is working :)